# What is the simplest and most intuitive way of computing the mixed strategy of a matrix game?

Tags: reference-request, self-learning, intuition, game-theory, algorithmic-game-theory

I have learned how to compute the mixed Nash equilibrium (NE) of a game many times, however, whenever I am faced with a matrix, I just cannot recall the exact way/logic of going about computing it.

I think the main problem is that the formulation process is just too long. I need to either pose it as a linear program (but who can remember how to formulate the objectives) or use a graphical method such as the best response curve. But I just keep on forgetting them because I lack the intuition.

For example, I am given the matrix,

[image]

I can visually check that (Fink, Fink) or $(2,2)$ is the pure NE. But I cannot remember how exactly to compute the mixed NE.

I have some rules of thumbs, which are unreliable, for example: by inspection I can see that the players probably want to earn a higher payoff than $1$ sometimes. So the players probably use a mixed strategy $(2/3, 1/3)$ of sorts to switch between Quiet and Fink. As I said, totally unreliable.

**What is the simplest and most intuitive method that you use to compute the NE for matrix games (and does it generalize to larger matrices)?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This game has no mixed-strategy NE. The only NE is (Fink, Fink) as playing fink is a strictly dominant strategy.

In mixed-strategy NEs players are indifferent between the strategies they play with positive probability. This gives a simple algebraic solution.

In your game let $q$ be the probability of playing Quiet. Note that the game is symmetric so it suffices to look at the indifference condition for one player.

In a mixed strategy NE player 1 is indifferent if $2q=3q+1(1-q)$. Rearranging would give the mixed-strategy NE if there was one. In this case we get $0=1$ and there is no mixed-strategy-NE.

You can also derive mixed-strategy NEs as the intersection of best-response functions.

Comment: Thanks! Although I am not sure what you meant by the indifference condition. And this only works for symmetric games with 2 strategies am I correct?

Comment: Indifference means that I only play multiple strategies with positive probability if each of those strategies gives the same expected payoff. Otherwise I could increase my expected payoff by not playing the strategy with lower expected payoff. This would contradict the definition of a Nash equilibrium.

Comment: The indifference argument works for non-symmetric games as well but then you get two equations and probabilities (likely) differ. It also works for more than two players or more strategies. Obviously, for three strategies a player can mix between two strategies or all three. You have to adjust the equation accordingly.